# Como trabalhar com o console do Javascript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

meu projeto está gerando esse erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É por conta desse método:

```
components: {
       VLayout: require('@/layouts/base'),

    },
```

Como será que faço para saber qual é o resultado do `VLayout` usando o `console.log()`?

Já tentei de várias maneiras para implementar o `console.log` no método mas está gerando sempre *`erros`* ao adiciona-lo.

Já tentei assim e não deu certo:

```
components: {
      const VLayout: require('@/layouts/base'),
        console.log(VLayout),
    },
```

Já tentei também assim e não deu certo:

```
components: {
      var teste = VLayout: require('@/layouts/base'),
        console.log(teste),
    },
```

Já tentei assim e não deu certo;

```
components: {
      var teste = VLayout: require('@/layouts/base'),
        console.log(teste);
    },
```

=====================================================================

Eu tentei dessa forma sendo que ele não imprimiu nada.

```
      <template>
  <v-layout>
    <v-grid variant="container">
      <v-row variant="xs-center">
        <v-col :variants="['xs-9', 'md-4', 'lg-3']">
          <v-card>
            <v-card-body>
              <v-form @submit.prevent.native="setQuery(query)">
                <v-input-group>
                  <v-icon variant="signifier">search</v-icon>
                  <v-text-field
                    variant="with-signifier"
                    v-model="query"
                    placeholder="Find artist"
                  />
                </v-input-group>
              </v-form>
            </v-card-body>
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
        <v-col :variants="['xs-3', 'md-4', 'lg-3', 'md-offset-4', 'lg-offset-6']">
          <v-button
            variant="circle"
            class="pull-right"
            @click.native="redirectToCreatePage"
          >
            <v-icon>add</v-icon>
          </v-button>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      <v-row>
        <v-col variant="sm">
          <v-table>
            <v-table-header>
              <v-table-row>
                <v-table-head>Name</v-table-head>
                <v-table-head>Birthday</v-table-head>
              </v-table-row>
            </v-table-header>
            <v-table-body>
              <v-table-row
                v-for="artist in artist.all"
                :key="artist"
                variant="body"
              >
                <v-table-cell>
                  <router-link :to="getArtistRoute(artist.id)">{{ artist.fullName }}</router-link>
                </v-table-cell>
                <v-table-cell>{{ artist.birthday }}</v-table-cell>
              </v-table-row>
              <v-table-row v-if="artist.all.length === 0">
                <v-table-cell colspan="3">Artists not found...</v-table-cell>
              </v-table-row>
            </v-table-body>
          </v-table>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      <v-row>
        <v-col variant="xs-justify">
          <v-card variant="inline">
            <v-card-body>
              <v-pagination
                :pagination="artist.pagination"
                :switch-page-function="setPage"
                variant="small"
              />
            </v-card-body>
          </v-card>
          <v-card variant="inline">
            <v-card-body>
              <v-select
                v-model="artist.pagination.limit"
                :items="pageNumbers"
              />
            </v-card-body>
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-grid>
  </v-layout>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    /**
     * The name of the layout.
     */
    name: 'artist-index',

    data() {
      return {
        artist: {
          all: [],
          pagination: {
            totalCount: 0,
            totalPages: 0,
            currentPage: 1,
            limit: 5,
          },
        },
        drawerActive: false,
        query: null,
        pageNumbers: [
          5,
          10,
          15,
        ],
      };
    },

    /**
     * The methods which the layout can use.
     */
    methods: {
      /**
       * Method used to hide the drawer.
       */
      hideDrawer() {
        this.drawerActive = false;
      },

      /**
       * Method used to toggle the drawer.
       */
      toggleDrawer() {
        this.drawerActive = !this.drawerActive;
      },

      /**
       * Method used to get the artist route.
       *
       * @param {Number} id The artist identifier.
       *
       * @returns {Object} The artist route.
       */
      getArtistRoute() {
        // todo
      },

      /**
       * Method used to redirect the user to the artist create page.
       */
      redirectToCreatePage() {
        // todo
      },

      /**
       * Method used to go to a different page.
       *
       * @param {Number} page The page number.
       */
      setPage() {
        // todo
      },

      /**
       * Method used to set the limit of the items being displayed.
       *
       * @param {Number} limit The limit of items being displayed.
       */
      setLimit() {
        // todo
      },

      /**
       * Method used to set the query of the search bar.
       * The results will be debounced using the lodash debounce method.
       */
      setQuery() {
        // todo
      },
    },

    /**
     * Available watchers for this page.
     */
    watch: {
      query(query) {
        this.setQuery(query);
      },
    },

    components: {
      VLayout: require('@/layouts/base'),
    },

  };

  function evidenciaConsole(valor){
  var traco = "--------------------------------------------------------------";
  console.log(traco + " Inicio " + traco);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(VLayout));
  console.log(VLayout);
  console.log(traco + "  Fim   " + traco);
}




</script>
```

Comment: Esse erro quer dizer que o componente não tem um método render ou um template pré-compilado. Podes mostrar mais código ou criar um exemplo online?

Comment: @Sergio eu não sei se você se recorda, mas o problema que estou tendo é o mesmo da postagem que fiz anterior a esse e que você mesmo comentou, como você não chegou a comentar mais nada na minha postagem anterior resolvi fazer outra postagem porque estou desesperado para resolver o meu problema, estou precisando muito de ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Porque você não tenta importar o seu componente desse jeito aqui.

Dessa maneira você consegue usar o console para exibir o objeto do componente.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <v-layout/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import VLayout from "./components/VLayout";

console.log(VLayout);

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    VLayout
  }
};
</script>
```

Montei um exemplo no [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/httpsptstackoverflowcomquestions241938c-5dgmi?file=/src/App.vue) e [versionei no Github](https://github.com/rafaelchagasb/answers-stackoverflow/tree/master/pt.stackoverflow.com/vuejs/42808261) para uso futuro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Criei esta função para mostrar qualquer coisa no console.log, até agora ela esta funcionando perfeitamente, se alguém quiser melhorar agradeço, quero ter uma função que possa mostrar qualquer variável, array ou o que for, tente utilizar e veja se o valor do VLayout vai aparecer com ela:

```
function evidenciaConsole(valor){
    var traco = "--------------------------------------------------------------";
    console.log(traco + " Inicio " + traco);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(valor));
    console.log(valor);
    console.log(traco + "  Fim   " + traco);
}
```

Criei esta variável traco para poder evidenciar no console o resultado, estou utilizando o JSON.stringify que converte um objeto javascript para uma string json e caso o valor for uma variável qualquer mostro ela com o console.log.

Comment: eu fiz uma atualização na minha postagem, poderia dá uma olhada por favor.

Comment: Se você colocar daquela forma ele não vai fazer nada, porque você colocou dentro da função e não à chamou, e removeu as partes mais importantes dela inclusive, você deve deixa a função como ela esta e usar no lugar do console.log usar ela evidenciaConsole, se possível coloque a função completa na sua pergunta.

Comment: como você pode ver eu atualizei novamente minha postagem e coloquem ela fora da função, ela tirou o erro, porém ela não apareceu no consoles do Browser, poderia dá uma olhada, e se estiver colocado da forma errado poderia redigir sua resposta e colocar sua resposta como sendo a minha pagina sendo que colocada a função da forma correta, por favor.